# When do Cloud saves happen? Mine are outdated

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I've played about 40 hours on my desktop, am now on a trip with my laptop, but after I loaded PoE, I found that the most recent save I had available was like 20 hours ago. What am I supposed to do to sync properly? I can't find any instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a little experiment:  I closed out of PoE on my desktop, instead of just putting it to sleep.  That seems to have done the trick.  I can start my latest save on my laptop.

Comment: So to spell it out - it would seem that it syncs upon closing the game. Makes sense.